# Do you get more DNA points by popping red and orange bubbles sooner?

Tags: plague-inc

When I infect a new country, a red bubble appears. Also, orange bubbles appear randomly on occasion. Usually these seem to give me somewhere between 1 and 4 DNA points when I pop them.

Are the number of points given determined randomly, or by how fast I pop the bubble after it appears?

Answer (score 7):

By my experience, it does not matter how fast you pop it, the number is random.

However, there is a DNA ability you can set so orange bubbles give more DNA points.

And if you wait too long, the bubble will disappear and you will lose all the points you could have gained from that bubble.